# SQL case statement logic issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, logic, case

I've written the following case statement to bring out a list of results for a particular subject.

```
SELECT upn,
       Min(CASE name
             WHEN 'English' THEN
               CASE
                 WHEN result IS NULL THEN 'U'
                 ELSE result
               END
           END) English
FROM   subject
GROUP  BY upn
```

Where the result is NULL I'd like to replace this with a U else bring through the results, but the above doesn't replace the NULLS. It works if I remove the `ELSE result` portion, but this obviously ends up displaying NULLS and Us. Something isn't quite right with my logic. Can anyone spot what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT upn,
       Min(CASE name
             WHEN 'English' THEN
               CASE
                 WHEN result IS NULL THEN 'U'
                 ELSE result
               END
            ELSE 'U'
           END) English
FROM   subject
GROUP  BY upn
```

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction. I did the following..SELECT upn,
       Min(CASE name
             WHEN 'English' THEN
               Result
            ELSE 'U'
           END) English
FROM   subject
GROUP  BY upn